# Can a weak Content Security Policy (CSP) contaminate web apps in the same domain?

Tags: security, browser, http-headers, content-security-policy, websecurity

If you have the following web app scenarios:

- `https://A.example.com` with a safe CSP
- `https://A.example.com/next.html` with a weak CSP

Does the second enables the first to somehow be breached because they are on the same sub-domain?

What if the scenario is:

- `https://A.example.com` with a safe CSP
- `https://B.example.com` with a weak CSP

Does the second enables the first to somehow be breached because they are on the same domain?

Comment: The policies have no effect on each other in either case. They’re completely-separate documents/resources — in spec terms, separate “top-level browsing contexts” — and in CSP completely-separate resources have completely-separate policies. For documents the only on policy that applies is the policy delivered with the document itself. See https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/#which-policy-applies. (In looking at that, note that the case for (embedded) *sub*resources of a document is a very different case than separate documents.) And of course two documents *can* be served with the same policy

Comment: In other words, in CSP there’s no automatic inheritance of policies within the same origin — no inheritance based on the document hierarchy no any other aspect. (Again of course if you want to serve all the documents in the origin with the same CSP policy, you *can* set the same policy for them every one of them by serving all with the same CSP header — but that’s not inheritance.)